Не удаётся получить строку из элемента с несколькими классами
Есть элемент <div class="название1 название2 название3">текст<sup></sup></div>
Не удаётся получить строку. Пробовал следующее:
const Element = document.querySelectorAll('.название1.название2.название3');
const Value = Element.innerText.trim();
Это js код, который внедряется в сайт через расширение, гугл выдаёт ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')
Так же пытался получить элемент через getElementsByClassName и получить из него текст с помощью textContent, но ошибка всегда одна: элемент не найден и невозможно получить текст
upd: Элемент с таким количеством классов один единственный на всей странице

При этом, при попытке получить текст из элемента с одним классом, всё работает

Ну так чего вы ожидаете, когда обращаетесь к коллекции элементов?

я в js новичок, я, можно сказать, вообще не особо понимаю, что происходит

Вам скорее всего нужно querySelector

так у меня зависает выполнение кода без каких-либо обозначений ошибок

Может лучше использовать обращение к элементу по id?
<div id="элемент" class="название1 название2 название3">текст<sup></sup></div>

const Element = document.querySelector('#элемент');

const Value = Element.innerText.trim();

Или используйте 1 класс вместо 3

Проблема в том, что элемент невозможно редактировать. Вот он есть с тремя классами, и всё, моя задача получить с него данные

Обращайтесь тогда к одному из классов. Но это больше всего не сработает, так как в документе может находится несколько элементов с такими классами, селектор просто выберет первый попавшийся. Разве только если вы знаете какой по счету именно тот элемент, что нужен вам - но это уже извращение...
